# Spiral path of an object when it gains some energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

Please I am a learner don't Mark the question as downvoted one.
My question is
Is there any examples other than 'charged particle in magnetic field' which go in spiral path when gain some energy during the course.
Here is the description
In a cyclotron the charged particle moves spirally just because it gains some energy between the 'dees' (the d shaped metallic conductors) due to electric field. Is this because of the necessity to maintain a constant frequency. The particle will go spiral by increasing it's radius of path. And the radius increase to maintain the frequency of the particle.
So is there any other examples where the particle go in spiral path not only to maintain it's frequency but some other factors.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the spiral path is that the force, in your example of a charged particle in a magnetic field, is always perpendicular to the direction of travel [this is a helical path, by the way, not a spiral] .  Your second example is of a machine that is designed, via sequential sections, to apply forces perpendicular to the current direction of travel.  That's similar to saying that proper control of the steering wheel will make an automobile drive in circles.

I have to admit I don't know whether it even makes sense to ask about particle "paths" in the presence of the strong or weak nuclear forces.